# MariaDB node replaces client request for host 127.0.0.1 with localhost

Tags: mariadb, mariadb-10.6

This seems very strange:

I have a MariaDB Galera cluster with three nodes, and each node has virtually the same configuration.

Since it's a Galera cluster, the database users are the same across all three nodes.

On node 1 and node 2 I get the expected hostname for the user:

```
mariadb --no-defaults -utheusername -p'thepassword' -h127.0.0.1 -e"select user()"
+-----------------------+
| user()                |
+-----------------------+
| theusername@127.0.0.1 |
+-----------------------+
```

However, on the third node it always ignores the request to use host `127.0.0.1` and replaces this with `localhost`:

```
mariadb --no-defaults -utheusername -p'thepassword' -h127.0.0.1 -e"select user()"
+-----------------------+
| user()                |
+-----------------------+
| theusername@localhost |
+-----------------------+
```

If I instead log in interactively (remove the `-e` option) and run the `status` command, it shows that the connection is over TCP/IP (not socket although the user's host is still `localhost`) on all the nodes:

```
Connection:     127.0.0.1 via TCP/IP
```

What could be the reason for this?